# UIScrollView, modal window , contents moving

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollview with contents twice the iphone screen size ( portrait).
it houses two imageviews. the user can scroll from to the other.
now on tapping on the inageviews I present another ViewController modally and show that image in more details.

The problem is that when the user dismisses that modal VC and returns to the original VC with the two images, both images shift within the contents of the scrollview by 160 points on the x axis, so the first image had an origin point of (0,0), and the second one had it at (320, 0), post dismissal of modal VC they switch to (-160, 0), and (160, 0) respectively.

I researched this and found that I have to handle the

```
  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];
      //here I try to manipulagte and foce another origin point, but it just doesn't 
     update
  }
```

Others found a solution like this

```
  [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero];
```

But this forces the scroll to go back to the first image even if the user had clicked on the second image!!

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to update the scroll view content size in ViewWillLayoutSubviews...See if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure as to why your scrollView would be automatically shifting out of position when you dismiss a modal VC, but I'd say your best bet is manually altering the content offset (as indicated in your answer). All you need to adjust is, when you tap on one of the images, keep a reference to that view (presumably an `ImageView`) in a property in the parent VC. When you call setContentOffset, do it like so (say you'd stored the view into a property called `selectedView`)

```
self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.selectedView.frame.origin.x, self.selectedView.frame.origin.y)
```

That should adjust it to the right position (you can add or subtract a little to the values to offset it a bit if you want)

Comment: still not working, the images do move by 160 pixels, I don;t know what other events fire after this?